# Why iterators are called fail safe or fail fast?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, concurrentmodification

Why are iterators called "fail-safe" and "fail-fast" even though `Iterator.remove()` doesn't throw any `ConcurrentModificationException` while iterating through a `Collection` (for example, `HashMap`) using `Iterator` ?

Comment: How the first 100 google results not answer the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Iterator.remove()` doesn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, but if **something else** (in another thread) modifies the `Collection` which backs the `Iterator` during iteration, then it will.

From the Java API docs for `java.util.ArrayList`; bold emphasis added by me:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are **fail-fast**: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, **in any way except** through the iterator's own remove or add methods, **the iterator will throw** a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

The next sentence of the same documentation then explains exactly what is meant by **fail-fast** in this case; again, bold emphasis added by me:

> Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator **fails quickly and cleanly**, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

In other words, the simple and safe thing to do, if another thread modifies the collection, is to cause a deliberate, explicit failure in the form of `ConcurrentModificationException`, rather than attempting to work out a non-failing, ie **fail-safe**, logic (such as having the modification show up via the `Iterator` depending upon whether that element has already been iterated over) which could be complex and error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

As name suggest fail-fast Iterators fail as soon as they realized that structure of Collection has been changed since iteration has begun. Structural changes means adding, removing or updating any element from collection while one thread is Iterating over that collection. fail-fast behavior is implemented by keeping a modification count and if iteration thread realizes the change in modification count it throws ConcurrentModificationException.

Contrary to fail-fast Iterator, fail-safe iterator doesn't throw any Exception if Collection is modified structurally
while one thread is Iterating over it because they work on clone of Collection instead of original collection and that’s why they are called as fail-safe iterator. Iterator of CopyOnWriteArrayList is an example of fail-safe Iterator also iterator written by ConcurrentHashMap keySet is also fail-safe iterator and never throw ConcurrentModificationException in Java.

Comment: Updating element of collection is not consider as a structure change operation and  don't cause ConcurrentModificationException, but adding and removing is

Answer (score 0):

- Fail-safe iterators means they will not throw any exception even if the collection is 
  modified while iterating over it.
- Whereas Fail-fast iterators throw an exception(ConcurrentModificationException) if the 
  collection is modified while iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer includes two points.

1. To the answer marked correct, it is important to add that fail-fast behaviour of iterators is not 100% reliable (and API docs state that). [The docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) it behaves on the best-effort basis and it is advised to use it only for bugs detection:

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the **fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs**

Thus, you probably **should** take this behaviour into account when writing code, but you definitely **must not** fully rely on it.

2. There is a very good [article](https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2016/07/27/there-is-no-such-thing-as-a-fail-safe-iterator-in-java/) on that. I know it was written later than asked. However, I find it useful to understand what's called `concurrent modification policy`.

So, there are four policies, and among them there is no fail-safe one:

1. Fail-fast
2. Weakly consistent
3. Snapshot
4. undefined

The conclusion from the [article](https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2016/07/27/there-is-no-such-thing-as-a-fail-safe-iterator-in-java/) says:

> After all this, where does “fail-safe” come into the picture? Answer: **it doesn’t**. The words “fail-safe” are never used in the Java SE specifications that describe the concurrent modification policy of a collection. As such, **there is no reliable, consistent definition of “fail-safe” for an Iterator**. One can attempt to apply the general concept of “fail-safety” to an Iterator, but this is open to varying, misleading, and even contradictory interpretations.
>
> Don’t use “fail-safe” to describe a Java Iterator. Instead, use one of the documented policies listed above.